# What kinds of algorithms work well with hundreds of thousands of output classes?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multi-class, many-categories

I have a limited amount of data for each class (about 100 samples), but I have about 100000 such classes. What kind of classification algorithm would work on this? (Apart from a NN with hierarchical Softmax)

Edit: I have about 100 data samples in the least frequent class. The final idea is to take a sample and assign a class to it. The actual data is textual and I am using glove 50d but with a PCA I can reduce them to about 10 (first component is about 30% of my info.). The situation is that I have a huge amount of data split into a large number of classes with each class having about 100 samples. Think of it as Authorship Attribution with 100k authors. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: I suspect that it all boils down to how different these classes are and the dimensionality of your samples.

Comment: Some classes are quite different from each other, some not so much.

Comment: What is the n for the least frequent class? How many variables do you have? Can you say more about your situation, your data, & your goals?

Comment: Thanks. What is the original number of features? Can you say what the situation is, & what the data actually are? (You don't have to be too specific & violate any confidentiality, just some sense of what were talking about here.)

Answer (score 0):

I think that first you should decrease number of your classes to e.g. 100 base classes and train a single classifier for these 100 base classes. Then for each of these base classes you should train separate subclassifiers (e.g. 200 subclassifier for each base class. Now you have 20000 classes.

Comment: Given the level of specificity in the Q, this does seem like a real answer to me. Moreover, it is an algorithm, it's just not random forest, neural network, etc.

Comment: I'll test this but I think there would a compounding effect of error that'll trickle down and reduce end accuracy drastically.